# Is searching for answers cursed?

Tags: bug, search

So I decided to have a little fun today and try to find the answer with the most down-votes on a few Stack Exchange sites. Pretty simple I just search for:

> is:answer

Sort by votes and clicked the last page. This seemed to work fine on Stack Overflow, but I noticed it did not when I tried it on Code Review. I figured at first that perhaps deleted answers were somehow included in the pagination, but I also tried this on Meta Stack Overflow and Software Engineering, and noticed the same thing: *using my search method, there are no answers found after page **666**, no matter how many pages of answers I see.*

Have I discovered an obscure bug (feature?), or is my search perhaps cursed?

Comment: I don't understand... when I [try this on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer), I see 33 pages of results (at 15 results per page) (or ten pages at 50 per page). Hand-editing the URL to go to a page number greater than 33 just sends me to page 33. For what it's worth, 666 x 15 = 10,000, which is a nice round number.

Comment: I recreated this on AskUbuntu, the search says  7547 pages but I get the no results page after page 200 https://askubuntu.com/search?page=201&tab=Relevance&q=%20%20%20%20%20%20is%3aanswer very strange.